# How to load image in their proper order

Tags: java, android, android-studio, server, async-await

I'm currently loading an undefinite number of online images in a TableLayout. To do so I use a `loadimage()` function that fetch the image url and then load it like so (not actual code):

```
for(i=0;i<numberofimagetoload;i++)
{
loadimage(i);
}

public void loadimage(int imagenumber)
{
String url = serverimage.getURL(imagenumber)
ImageView.loadImageFromURL(url)
}
```

But images are loading in complete disorder, mainly because of the fetching time.
My question is: "How can I wait for the loadimage function to complete before moving on?"

Comment: That will depend on how `loadImageFromURL(url)` is implemented. But in short you need to find a way to turn an async call in to a synchronous one so that you can wait for each load to complete. That's the real question you need to ask

Answer (score 0):

- Try Linked hash set. It prevents duplicate values and maintains the insertion order.
- ArrayList can also help.
- For network call use retrofit. It returns an object in response.